# Alternative to venn diagram

Tags: visualization, data-visualization

Is there a visualization format that shows overlapping proportion of categories in data, but more precise than venn diagram? Also venn diagram is typically used to show 2 or 3 categories, more than that it gets confusing.

Stacked bar, waterfall etc could show proportion per categories, but assuming no overlapping between these categories.

So for overlapping categories, what's the best way to show their proportion, including the proportion that overlaps with another category?

Comment: This is not worth a real data-vis expert point of view, but you can display your data as an oriented graph. Each node would be a category or category intersection, size would be proportion and links would indicate a inclusion relationship. Just a thought

Answer (score 8):

You should check [UpSet](http://caleydo.org/tools/upset/). They also have an R package ( [UpsetR](https://github.com/hms-dbmi/UpSetR) ) and the web version [here](http://vcg.github.io/upset/).

Really cool tool!

The idea is that the relations are sorted as you wish ( i.e. by the number of elements ) in the bottom panel and then in the top panel you see the actual numbers in a bar plot. I think it's really useful to focus the attention on the important things in

Answer (score 2):

What I initially described as an oriented graph with inclusion relashionship has a more precise scientific name, it's called a [Hasse diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram).

A Hasse diagram is used to represent a partially ordered set elements and their combinaisons. In your application, that would be categories and their intersections.

Depending of your audience (academic, professional etc.), you may use it as is or use it as inspiration to make a custom data visualisation.

Comment: it's a very thoughtful suggestions. i do need to communicate to business users rather than academics so will need to have a thought around that.  thanks!